# WPF DataGrid doesn't fire any events

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My datagrid doesn't fire any events, and I don't know why?
Here is how I populate my datagrid:

```
         public static void FillDataGridTickets(DataGrid grid,bool fill=true)
         {
                 jsonresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TicketsGrid>>(result);
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new ThreadStart(() => grid.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = jsonresponse })));
         }
```

This is called from a different class from where the datagrid is (I removed some code to not be so big). Everything is working fine but events did not fire

And this is my XAML:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="ViewTicketsGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="513" Margin="0,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="999" ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
                  CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="Black" RowBackground="#061038"  AlternationCount="2" BorderBrush="#891800FF" Foreground="#DDFFFFFF" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True" SelectedCellsChanged="ViewTicketsGrid_SelectedCellsChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Solved" Click="Solved_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Header="Unsolved" Click="Unsolved_Click" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
```

and object class

```
   public class TicketsGrid
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        public string user { get; set; }
        public string to_user { get; set; }
        public string information { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my pc, the power went out and my windows bugged.I reallized it after notepad texts was just empty lines . I tried to debug it for more then 3 hours... , sorry guys.